# problem with description

Tags: description

I use the description environment to type itemized lists ... there are many code fragments in the form

```
\begin{description}
\item [(1)] some text
\item [(2)] some text
\item [(3)] some text
\item [(4)] some text
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item [(11)] some text
\item [(22)] some text
\item [(33)] some text
\item [(44)] some text
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item [(111)] some text
\item [(222)] some text
\item [(333)] some text
\item [(444)] some text
\end{description}
```

The problem is that for each first line, namely the lines

```
\item [(1)] some text
\item [(11)] some text
\item [(111)] some text
```

the next message is displayed in the log file:

```
Missing control sequence inserted
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
```

This problem does not seem to affect the outcome of the process but i want to suppress it .. can anyone helf me with this situation?

ANSWER ==> I solved the problem !! In my code i use the commands

```
\setlist[itemize,1]{font=\color{itemizeColor1}\bfseries,label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{font=\color{itemizeColor2}\bfseries,label=$\blacktriangleright$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{font=\color{itemizeColor3}\bfseries,label=$\bigstar$}
```

to setup the font and color of the labels but with description, the correct syntax is just

```
\setlist[description,1]{font=\color{itemizeColor1}\bfseries}
\setlist[description,2]{font=\color{itemizeColor2}\bfseries}
\setlist[description,3]{font=\color{itemizeColor3}\bfseries}
```

and the last 'label' argument was the one that caused the problem. When i deleted it, the problem solved ...

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete but small document, which we can copy and  compile in out computers and will show your problem.

Comment: Why don't you use the `enumerate` environment?

Comment: @Tiuri: The `enumerate` environment does not create `111` etc. out of the box

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Agreed, not out of the box, but not unsolvable either.

Comment: @Tiuri: Easy with `enumitem`, but the error here is something completely different

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Well, I know that. That's why I'm asking the OP if there is some reason to stick to `description`.

Comment: this code is from the Problems section at the end of each chapter of the book I translate. For some reason when i use itemize with long labels e.g \item [1.110] or something like this, the label does not aligned correctly with the left margin but extends beyond this margin to the left. I noticed that the description environment does not have this problem and that's why i use it .. after all, as far as i know, with description we can use any label we want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want something more or less like this, where the enumeration is automatic, and the labels do not flow into the margin, with the `wide` option, which implies labels are `left-aligned`; no `right-aligned`, which is the default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setlist[enumerate]{wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *, font = \bfseries}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label = (\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label = (\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*) }
\setlist[enumerate, 3]{label = (\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic*)}

\begin{enumerate}[ widest = (0)]
\item some text
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin = *]
\item some text
\item some text
\end{enumerate}
\item some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item some text
\item some text
\item some text
\end{enumerate}
\item some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item some text. Some more text. Some more text.Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.Some more text. Some more text.
\item some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item some text
\item some text
\item some text
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item [(4)] some text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]